# Base Number Addition

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that $p$ is prime and $1007_p+306_p+113_p+125_p+6_p=142_p+271_p+360_p$. How many possible values of $p$ are there?

I suppose I solve this by putting in $p^2$ and $p^1$ for the hundreds and tens digits?

I did that so I got $p^3$  + 24 = $p^2$ + 14p

Comment: I finally got to the equation, $p^3$ + 24 = $p^2$ + 14p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must have that $p^3+7+3p^2+6+p^2+p+3+p^2+2p+5+6=p^2+4p+2+2p^2+7p+1+3p^2+6p$, meaning that $p^3-p^2-14p+24=0$. But the only prime solutions of this can be factors of $24$, i.e. $2$ and $3$. But $7$ is not a digit in base $2$ or $3$, so there are $\boxed{0}$ possible $p$!

Comment: Well really $1007_2$ is saying you have $1\cdot 2^3+0\cdot 2^2+0\cdot 2^1+7\cdot 2^0$. You can just rewrite this as $1111_2$.

Comment: I don't see how you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct. Now you just need to solve the equation for $p$. You have:

$$
\begin{split} && p^3+24=p^2+14p \\ &\implies& p^3-p^2-14p+24=0 \\ &\implies& (p-2)(p^2+p-12)=0 \\ &\implies& (p-2)(p-3)(p+4)=0 \end{split}
$$

So the only primes that will work are $p=2$ or $p=3$.

Comment: I'm sorry but 7 is not in base 3 or 2.

Comment: But you can always re-write the numbers so that they are 'properly' in base 3 or 2. So $1007_2$ becomes $1111_2$. Similar to saying that $1400$ is fourteen hundred, rather than 1 thousand, four hundred.